# What language(s) are programs like ActiveInbox written in?

Tags: plugins, browser

I want to write something similar to  [ActiveInbox](http://www.activeinboxhq.com/).

In addition to original ActiveInbox, I need to add logic that will perform some actions on the emails that come.

What language(s) are programs like ActiveInbox written in?

Thank you

Comment: [Gmail is written in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525199/what-server-side-language-is-gmail-written-in),

Comment: @duffymo, why you closed my post? what it has to do that Gmail is written in JAVA? With all respect, but I think you closed without understanding! I'm talking about the browser plugin that will do some actions with mails. So I want to know in what language I need to write this? In Javascript?

Comment: I think I did.  Gmail is written in Java.  Since ActiveInBox is a Gmail plug-in, I think that's germane.  I don't care what language you write it in.

Comment: Um, that referenced question wasn't closed...

Comment: Start with the [Chrome plugin and extension developers guide here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devguide.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activeinbox is a browser plugin, written in Javascript.  It's easy to have a look inside: download the xpi (the Firefox version of the plugin).  An xpi file is a zipfile, so open it with your zipfile manager of choice.

After that you should head over to [Mozilla's developer site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) or [a Chrome extension development tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html) to learn how to wite a Firefox/Chrome plugin.

Comment: So, if I want to write some logic that on every email that I get I want to put it on some label or delete it or save it to HD, I do it on JavaScript? I mean I use some Google API that will let me to get the email, to place it in label...,but the call it self I do in JavaScript, right?

Comment: all what I need is the purpose of the browser plugin, so all has to be written in JavaScript, right?

Comment: @theateist yes, probably.  First try to understand how activeinbox works by reading its code, you'll see that it's far from trivial what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions can be written in pure Javascript on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Hawy, Is there are other languages I can/need to use?