# What languages I will need in order to write browser plugin that will work with GMAIL?

Tags: plugins, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# plugin for Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881466/c-plugin-for-google-chrome)
>   [What language(s) are programs like ActiveInbox written in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620988/what-languages-are-programs-like-activeinbox-written-in)

I need to write browser plugin, mainly to chrome. This plugin will work with **GMAIL**. It will track incoming mails and do some actions(put label, delete mail...). - similar what gmail already does by filter option.

My question is: what languages I will need to do this, only JavaScript?

P.S. I've already asked similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620988/what-languages-are-programs-like-activeinbox-written-in), but it was closed. I hope this time I explained exactly what I need.

Thank you